# Jammed pawl on 8-speed shimano shifter

Tags: shimano, shifter

[image: Shimano st-1055 shifter]

I'm doing up a bike that seems to have been sitting in a shed for the last 25 years. 
It has a Shimano 105SC groupset (93-99) with 8-speed st-1055 STI shifters. 
As seems to be the norm for these units the factory grease has congealed into a solid mass over time.

I found a good [forum post](https://forum.cyclinguk.org/viewtopic.php?t=124472) and [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkGNN_2CfCY) on how to partially disassemble them for cleaning and re-greasing.

It was fairly straightforward - it took some time to work all the parts and flush the old gunk out of the works but both units are now totally clean and have no signs of wear and the left unit shifts through the positions with ease.

However the right-hand unit is still jammed. After spending much time I have figured out that the issue is with one of the pawls - I believe it to be the one referred to as the index pawl in the forum post linked above.

The other 3 pawls move freely on their shafts and spring back gently. However the index pawl is very stiff. I've spend a lot of time spraying lubricant onto the pin and working it but it remains stuck. Based on that, and on the feel of it, I think it's more likely to be due to the tension on the spring rather than the shaft being gummed up.

When shifting, the bar (see picture) moves in the direction of the arrow and engages with the rear of the pawl. This should cause it to pivot and allow the mechanism to shift. However the pawl is so stiff the pressure of the bar is not enough to make it move. I can use a small flat bladed screwdriver to depress the rear of the pawl to force it to pivot, which requires a fair amount of force, and this allows the unit to shift as normal.

There doesn't appear to be any way of adjusting the tension on the pawl spring.

EDIT:
Alternatively could it be that the bar is slightly bent and is not engaging fully with the pawl? It's hard to tell...

[image: shimano st1055 - bar]

Comment: What about the miss-placed spring in the second photo?

Comment: yeah, that's on the downshift drive pawl - the spring is off-line on the back there but the pawl seems to be working fine anyway - it lifts off when then inner lever is engaged and clicks back into position nicely

Comment: I've been told that the only option at this stage is a full stripdown and reassembly. The chances of even getting in back together correctly are low.